# Javascript - using a string to output HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which takes a load of arrays and outputs them to a series of li tags.

```
function pushOutput() {
    for(i=1; i<23; i++)
    {   
        var x = eval('result'+ i);
        if(x!=undefined)
        {   
            var output = '';
            if(x.constructor == Array)
            {
                for(n=0; n<x.length; n++)
                {
                    output += x[n] + '<br />';
                }
            }
            else { output = x + '<br />';}
            $('.resultOut'+i).text(output); 

        }
    }
}
```

the HTML it gets output too looks something like

```
<ul>
  <li class="resultOut1></li>
  <li class="resultOut2></li>
  <li class="resultOut3></li>
  ..... etc
</ul>
```

The code is supposed to add a 
 tag at the end if there are multiple results with the aim of starting a new line.

However what happens is I actually get the br output as part of the text. so the result to the user looks something like

```
  value1 <br /> value2 <br />
```

instead of

```
value1 <br />
value2 <br />
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try `.html` method instead of `.text`

Comment: Hi Windkiller, why shouldnt you use eval? whats wrong with it>?

Comment: I think eval can be replaced with
`var x = window["result" + i];`
(if result* variables are global)

Comment: but what benefit does that have?

Comment: im just wondering what the actually problem with the eval method is

Comment: For example http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/

Comment: @jQuery00 - `eval()` is not usually recommended, but your suggested replacement is not very helpful in that it only works on globals. A better solution is to refactor the `result` variables as an array.

Comment: Eval in all languages as I know is called root of all evil. It is something like black magic. You can use black magic for good purposes, but it is still black magic. 99% of your code can be done without it. If you reach that 1%, then you should look for different way on another level (like change language). Eval is overpowered function, but hard to debug, hard to understand, hard to maintain and it is easy to make a mistake which can cause serious security problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need use `html()` instead of `text()`

`$('.resultOut'+i).html(output);`